# JSSOR Slider - How stop thumbnail navigator onHover?

Tags: javascript, jssor

I'm using the thumbnailNavigator with ActionMode:3(onHover)...normally the ThumbnailNavigator after changed the slide, put the hovered thumbs on first line( i'm using vertical orientation)...i wanna stop this movement, i.e. after changed slide stop the thumb moving...is that possible?
Fundamentally i'm searching onHoverStop option for thumnailNavigator....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug, i fixed it just now. Please download the latest version.

You can set `$PauseOnHover: 12` (means freeze on mouse over) for thumbnails.

```
$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
    ...,
    $PauseOnHover: 12,
    ...
}
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html